# Drupal Commerce Hook - Extra validation before adding to cart

Tags: hooks, commerce

I was looking for a hook that will fire after a user hits the add to cart button.
The commerce api isn't very clear about this.

What I'm trying to is:
Add an extra validation for a customized product (date field). 
So basically I want to interrupt the adding to the cart process and proceed if validation is ok, and lead the user back if not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [hook_commerce_cart_product_add](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.api.php/function/hook_commerce_cart_product_add/DCul) is what you're after. I couldn't find any examples for preventing the line item being added to the cart but at the very least you should be able to use drupal_goto to interupt the process. You might also want to look at the Rules events\actions provided by Commerce.

Comment: Could I use hook_form_alter for this task, too? I was thinking about something like this: `function xxx_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'xxx')
  {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'xxx_custom_validate_function';
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to run a `hook_form_alter` to add your own validation callback. An example may look like the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function commerce_stock_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, "commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form") === 0) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_add_to_cart_validate';
  }
}
```

Your call back can then check `$form_state['values']['quantity']` or `$form_state['values']['product_id']`, for example, to check quantity and the product added.

A great example of hooking into the add to cart form is in the Commerce Stock module, for advanced usages: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_stock/tree/commerce_stock.module#n64

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this post can help you.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1292742